# Fastest way to get all files from a particular revision?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to find the fastest way to get all the files from a particular changeset; I don't care about the history.

The best thing I've found so far is to `cd` into the repository, and then

```
hg archive -u <changeset> /path/to/put/files
```

But I'm finding even that is quite slow on a large repository, even though it doesn't create the `.hg` folder.

I was thinking maybe I could use `hg update` instead because that seems to run a bit faster, but I don't want to update the current directory, I want the files to be written to a new directory outside the current repo. Is that possible?

Or is there some other quick way?

Comment: There is no better or faster way in general. `hg archive` is meant for exactly that purpose and it's usually the best way to export the repository state as of a certain revision.

Comment: Even after an update (with the undesired side-effects) the files would need to be copied out..

Comment: Another way is to [clone to a particular revision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148234/how-can-you-clone-a-mercurial-repository-as-of-a-specific-changeset) and and then to ["uninit"](https://github.com/wertarbyte/etckeeper/blob/master/uninit.d/50vcs-uninit). Will it be faster or better in any way? I doubt it (as it also duplicates the initial store's ancestor history); but it will accomplish the requested task without modifying the current working copy. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following to speed things up a bit:

```
hg archive --config ui.archivemeta=false /path/to/target
```

This option suppresses the generation of `.hg_archival.txt`, which can sometimes be relatively expensive to generate.

Also, `hg update` can be faster locally because not all files have to be updated (only the ones that were changed relative to the current revision). A fresh update after a `hg clone -U` or `hg share -U` should not be any faster.

You can try a recursive hardlink (via `cp -al` or a similar tool) followed by `hg update`, but then you have to be extra careful, because modifying files in one checkout can affect the ones in the other. This is only an option if you want a read-only copy or if you know (as in, *positively know*, not just guess) that you won't do any in-place modification of any of the files.

Comment: Hardlink might work. I'm just using it to do a build and then deleting the entire directory afterwords which should prevent accidental modification. Thanks for the suggestions!